# What is this jQuery selector doing exactly? $('<a/>', { ... });

Tags: jquery

I'm debugging through a 3rd party JS library and I noticed this jQuery selector statement.

I'm used to simple $([element]) selectors, so this is throwing me off.

```
$('<a/>', {
    id: 'specialId',
    href: '#',
    'class': 'button-next',
    html: 'SomeText'
}).appendTo($('#specialDivId'));​
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I rarely find this more clear than building the HTML string myself. It's only helpful when all the attributes are variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's generating a DOM object.

This is similar to doing

```
$("<a id='specialId'></a>") ....
```

You can then use that to .appendTo something else!

Answer (score 3):

It creates a new element `<a>`, set its options (id, href etc.) and append it to `#specialDivId`